# What caused iPad Air to go black screen and not power up?

Tags: ipad

When I was on my iPad Air last night an Apple warning appeared.
Usually I can go into settings and clear it.
This one kept flashing.
I clicked the button on bottom left to re-log in.
After, I entered my password, the tablet went black and unresponsive.
Now it won't power up?

I am unsure of what to do now, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: And the warning would be......  It's just a bit difficult to help you diagnose it when there's nothing to go on.

Answer (score 1):

[It could be many things](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251215/iphone-5s-wont-charge). I would go through this checklist and possible ask a follow on question when one item fails or you can't complete the checklist to rule out common reasons for this:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412